# How To Remove Text from TD tag and Create a Select Element Inside?

Tags: jquery, html

Below is my HTML markup

```
<tr id="row36" ng-show="!hiddenrow[36]" role="row" class="odd">
<td id="edit36" class="sorting_1"> 
<a id="editbtn_36" class=""><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="color:green"></i></a>
</td>
<td>36</td>
<td contenteditable="true">11443</td>
<td contenteditable="true">Mr . jack</td>
<td id="dp36" contenteditable="true">06-10-2017</td>
<td id="dp36" contenteditable="true" class="form-controlj">04-12-2017</td>
<td contenteditable="true" dropdown="true" class="">State Here</td>
<td contenteditable="true">Oklohoma</td>
<td contenteditable="true">N/A</td>
<td>21-11-2017</td>
</tr>
```

The 7th  Tag has a custom attribute as `dropdown="true"`

On Click of this cell i want to remove its text and show a dropdown here to select new value into cell.

Below is my Approach for this

```
  $('td[dropDown=true]').focus(function () {
        var params = {
            url: '@Url.Action("GetStateJson", "CGT")',
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (result) {
                var sel = "<select>";
                for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                    sel += "<option value='" + result[i].Value + "'>" + result[i].Text + "</option>"
                }
                sel += "</select>";
                $(this).html("");
                $(this).html(sel);
            },
            error: function (result)
            { alert('Warning! It failed.'); }
        };
        $.ajax(params);
    });
```

I am calling an MVC JsonResult Method to get raw data for Dropdown.

Its Working good till creating HTML markup in variable sel but below two lines not seems to do anything

```
$(this).html("");
$(this).html(sel);
```

Neither Remove text from cell neither show any dropdown , neither any error in console.

> Note: I have Checked and markup generated for dropdown is valid (no
>   problem in that)

Comment: add this as your first line inside your function `var $thisTD = $(this)` and then use this variable for setting your HTML like `$thisTD.html(sel)`... the `$(this)` inside your success function does not point to your `td` as you intend but rather it points to the AJAX object.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy , Perfect , But how can i remove the Dropdown After Selecting Value , i Just want to leave new Value there . Dropdown Should be gone After Selection

Comment: you would need to bind a on `change` event to the newly appended dropdown, and within this change event you will again manipulate the html of the `td` by removing the dropdown and adding your text in place of it.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Thanks A lot for the Hint